# uniq - how to ignore IP address?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, uniq

I have the following:

```
cat /var/log/example.log | cut -d ' ' -f 3,4,5,6 | sort -u | uniq
```

The result has several thousand lines but I would like to cut this down to show the actual activity and to do this, I would need to exclude/ignore the IP address

So the log has records such as:

```
2021-12-30 19:46:44 Invalid heartbeat from X.X.X.X
2021-12-30 19:46:44 X.X.X.X sent a malformed request
2021-12-30 19:46:44 Login from X.X.X.X failed due to bad username
2021-12-30 19:46:44 Failed login from this IP X.X.X.X
```

There are tens of thousands of records - how do I get the activity i.e.

```
Invalid heartbeat from 
sent a malformed request
Login from failed due to bad username
Failed login from this IP
```

Thanks

Comment: `sort -u` = `sort | uniq` so you never need `sort -u | uniq`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sed` to remove the IP address before sorting:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 3- /var/log/example.log | sed -E 's/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}//g' | sort -u
```

`cut -f 3-` - this will get you all fields from the 3rd until the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `awk` solution, here it is

```bsh
awk '
{
        for (i = 1; i <= NF - 2; i++) {
                $i = $(i + 2)
        }
        NF -= 2
        gsub(/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/, "", $0)
        print
}
' /var/log/example.log | sort -u
```

Comment: The effect of decrementing `NF` is undefined by POSIX so some awks (e.g. GNU awk) will remove fields from the end of the line, but other awks will ignore the instruction completely and yet other awks could do anything else with that. To remove the last 2 fields portably in any POSIX awk would be `sub(/[[:space]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*){2}$/,"")`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this works better.

```
awk '{ gsub(/[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}/, ""); $1 = $2 = "";
    gsub(/^ +| +$/, "") } !seen[$0]++' /var/log/example.log
```

No need to rely on `\s` and `\s+` when we can just allow contiguous white spaces to be converted to a single space after `$1 = $2 = ""`.

Thanks to [Ed Morton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/133219/ed-morton).